# iScsiPrt errors preventing system from returning from display rest

Tags: windows-7, iscsi

I am encountering a weird error in Windows 7 x64 Ultimate SP1. At random intervals, when coming back to the computer after being away long enough for the screen to rest, it will instead come back to a completely black screen (not off, but actively displaying black). The only way to get the system back to a usable state is to hard reset.

Error logs indicate iScsiPrt errors 1 and 70 every time this happens. However, there are absolutely no favorite targets set in iScsi Initiator, so standard solutions which involve removing a bad connection are inapplicable. To the best of my knowledge, iScsi has never been used on this system at all.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?